# Wso2 API manager getting error in Publisher while adding API: "Error while adding role permissions to API"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

When trying to publish an API in Wso2 API manager's Publisher getting the following Error:  "Error while adding role permissions to API".

Have checked the roles of the user adding the api. Also the user is having the admin role. 
 The issue goes away if I set the Visibility on Store to “Restricted by Roles”  and Visible to Roles to “Admin”.
If I set it to Public or “Internal/subscriber” the error comes up!

[image]

Comment: Post the error you see in the log.

Comment: There is no error in the logs. This is really a strange error. The popup comes but remaining functionilty works though(Api gets published). logs are all info. No errors in.

Comment: face the same in private windows too?

Comment: @Bee In Firefox Incognito mode … it seemed like it didn’t come up the first time, but then it started coming up after the first try.
 
In Chrome .. doesn’t seem to come up in an incognito window !!!

Comment: seems like a caching issue. did u change any UIs?

Comment: no didnt change any UI

Comment: This issue happened on only one environment  . In Dev environment and local environment it's working fine.  Test environment which is similar to a Dev environment this happened

Comment: @crystalthinker Go to carbon and check if the role/permission already exist for the API name you have given. This might be the issue of generating role/permission with same name.
Also check `synapse` folder and validate your api `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the loaded swagger file, I noticed that the API name (title) was incorrect. After correcting the names for swagger and upload, this issue was sorted.